# How to set proxy server to work from the command line

Tags: networking, command-line, internet, proxy

I have set up my proxy server so that it works through the browser ( in firefox: edit > preferences > advanced < network < settings ).

I also got it working from the command line ( in system settings: network < network proxy ) which has been working fine for the last few weeks.

Suddenly connecting to the internet through the command line has stopped working but connecting through the browser still works fine.

Does anyone know why this could happen and how to fix it? Surely if I can access the internet through the browser, why can't I from the command line?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what might have happened to your system, but you may be interested in setting those in your terminal/command line:

```
export http_proxy="http://user:password@proxy_server:port"
export https_proxy="https://user:password@proxy_server:port"
```

Then run the

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can actually check what shows:

```
echo $http_proxy
```

(btw - you may use this way for `ftp_proxy`, too)

Comment: Tried that before and it didn't work but this time it did. Maybe because I reset afterwards. thanks.